# Display child posts from a certain category

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have a custom posts (called "radio-shows") on which I wish to display posts from a certain category but only *if they are children of the custom posts* page.

So far I have managed to display all posts in the category:

```
<ul class="podcasts">
  <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=7&posts_per_page=30&order=DESC' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
  ?>
    <li class="track-list-item"><?php the_content();?></li>
  <?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

What can I add to the code above to make it display, on each custom post page, only its child posts?

Comment: Your question is little confusing to me. Is custom post type `radio-shows` hierarchical like default `page` post type ?

And you want to display only child items when user is on a radio show page ? or something else ?

Comment: I want to display child items when user is on a radio show page like [urban sunsets radio show](http://urbansunsets.com/radio-shows/urban-sunsets-radio-show/). There is an archive-radio-show.php page if that is what you mean by _hierarchical_.

Comment: Do you have the following dropdown (http://prntscr.com/f459oc) on edit page of radio show ? This is what I mean by hierarchical

Comment: I don't have the dropdown. It is a post, not a page. I used the _Toolset Types plugin_ to create the custom posts and their custom fields.

Comment: So how do you assign child items ? I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Are you using any custom taxonomy connected to the post type or whatever else you're using to understand child/parent items ?

Comment: The parent-child relationship is given by a characteristic of Toolset types.
See it in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89XOH.png).

Comment: It looks like you're using a custom field for this. Can you find and supply the custom field key ? You'll be able to find it on the place where you've created the option inside toolset plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post_parent argument for the query. Here is a slightly modified version of your code:

```
<ul class="podcasts">
    <?php 
    global $post;
    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=7&posts_per_page=30&order=DESC&post_parent=' . $post->ID );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();?>
        <li class="track-list-item"><?php the_content();?></li>
    <?php 
    endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, it looked promising so I tried it ot and now the page does not display anithing. Could this be because it is a custom post (radio-show)? The template is content-show.php

Comment: What if I want to filter results by author?